# How to organize low cardinality data in DynamoDB

Tags: amazon-dynamodb

What is the best way to structure a table with low cardinality and high scale in DynamoDB? For example, suppose I have an application where a user can create posts and other users can view these posts. What should I use for partition key and sort key? I could have a PK of posts and SK of a Unix timestamp, which would allow me to query the most recent posts globally. Note that I want to view all posts and not just the posts for a specific user.

If I take this approach I would be consistently reading from the same partition, which could slow my performance and potentially hit the RCU or WCU limits for the partition.

Can this be mitigated with DAX?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

One technique is write-sharding.  This is when you store your data across partitions to make more efficient use of the database.  For example, you may choose to divide posts into partitions based on the month the post was written.  If you decided to store blog posts monthly, you could store all posts in November 2020 in a partition with key `POSTS#2020-11-01`.

AWS has [documentation about write sharding](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/amazondynamodb/latest/developerguide/bp-partition-key-sharding.html) that goes into greater depth.

You should check out the AWS DynamoDB Office Hours series on Twitch/Youtube.  Rick Houlihan, a DynamoDB wizard, walks through all sorts of data modeling examples.  In [this episode](https://youtu.be/em860yYs7uw), he modeled a Wordpress blog in DynamoDB.  I've found walkthroughs like this to be extremely helpful.

Comment: Thanks Seth. If I did a monthly (or even daily) and had lots of posts wouldn't I still run into the same issue? If I use one of the techniques they mention I still have to query each of those shards. This seems excessive if I only wanted the last 10 posts. Is there a way to deal with that use case? Will watch Rick's videos, thank you!

Comment: The link I posted to the AWS docs addresses this specific issue.  It describes appending a suffix (random or calculated on a known attribute, like post ID) to the date partition key (e.g. 2020-12-01.1, 2020-12-01.5, etc) which will help distribute the data beyond a simple date partition.  Another strategy is to calculate the most recent posts each time a new post is created and store them in a singleton item (e.g PK = POSTCACHE).  You could even duplicate the singleton object (POSTCACHE#1, POSTCACHE#2,....POSTCACHE#N) and fetch one of them randomly when reading.

Comment: Thank you for your help

Comment: I just wanted to add that if you need to control the number of shards, then using UTF-8 code points to calculate a suffix works great. An example on how to calculate this can be found at https://gist.github.com/rune-vikestad/07fa8a21f76b9304e0569414376bcdf2